# Error when deploying laravel app on DigitalOcean App Platform

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean-apps

I have an app that has been deployed on DigitalOcean App Platform.  Ever since making the latest changes I keep getting the error

bash: line 1: heroku-php-apache2: command not found

Build phase runs to completion and then the deploy fails.  I'm lost.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

I have tried updating node and npm.  Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and running npm install.  Tried changing Procfile.

Comment: Try making a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Digital Ocean is not Heroku. it looks like a .sh script is ran while deploying on Digital Ocean and it's looking for Apache on Heroku

Comment: I ended up figuring this out.  While watching my build logs, I noticed that PHP was never being installed.  It seemed to be that App Platform was not detecting composer.json and it was building it as a Node app and every rebuild built from the build cache and kept building it the same way.  I messed with the App Spec and added the feature to use Ubuntu 18 instead of 22.04 which forced it to build differently and it added PHP.  After the rebuild I removed the Ubuntu 18 feature in the App Spec and built it again with PHP buildpack present.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Glad you solved it, man! If you answer yourself in an answer instead of a comment, you can mark it as resolved

Comment: That would be a good idea.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out. While watching my build logs, I noticed that PHP was never being installed. It seemed to be that App Platform was not detecting composer.json and it was building it as a Node app and every rebuild was built from the build cache and kept building it the same way. I messed with the App Spec and added the feature to use Ubuntu 18 instead of 22.04 which forced it to build differently and it added PHP. After the rebuild, I removed the Ubuntu 18 feature in the App Spec and built it again with PHP buildpack present. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In you App spec add the following:

```yaml
features:
- buildpack-stack=ubuntu-18
```